# Iptables: Difference between RELATED and ESTABLISHED state?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, connection

I've tried reading many articles on the internet but none of them are quite clear. I also know similar question has been posted here before but none of them explain my situation. Earlier I ended up wasting 2-3 hours because of this.

Manual says:

> NEW -- meaning that the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in both directions, and
>
> ESTABLISHED -- meaning that the packet is associated with a connection which has seen packets in both directions,
>
> RELATED -- meaning that the packet is starting a new connection, but is associated with an existing connection, such as an FTP data transfer, or an ICMP error.

My iptables on Server look like:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Flush old rules
    iptables -F

# Loopback
    iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow responses from OUTPUT connection
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Apache
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Whenever I try `curl --verbose https://server_ip/` from my PC, it works perfectly. But when I tried this from inside the server after SSHing into it, it always stuck at `CLIENT HELLO`. Why it is happening? Note: `curl --verbose http://server_ip/`(without SSL) worked perfectly from both local PC and server.

After I executed `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT`, it started working from inside the server too.  Again why it started working?

Manual says `RELATED -- meaning that the packet is starting a new connection`. Is it a security risk? Can a client open a connection to a different port using this? When it is useful?

Comment: In a packet capture, what's the first packet you see with RELATED allowed which you **don't** see without the RELATED rule in there? My gut tells me this has something to do with the fact that, when you make a connection to the external-facing port, you are _also_ allocating an external port. In other words, if your server's IP were 10.0.0.5, to connect to that IP from within the server you'd need to allocate a client port (say, 5029, to pick a random port) on that same IP address (so, 10.0.0.5:5029).

Comment: I think the problem likely happens when 10.0.0.5:443 (https) tries to send packets back to 10.0.0.5:5029, which causes those packets to be run through the firewall ruleset, and for some reason those response packets are being blocked because they're for neither a NEW connection (they're SYN-ACK packets), nor are they for an ESTABLISHEDj connection (it's a half-open connection). However, I know it isn't *exactly* that, because if it were HTTP should also be failing.

Comment: Short version? Run a packet capture with the rule, another packet capture without the rule, and show us both captures. Or look at them yourself and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need the `NEW,ESTABLISHED` part later on. You can just use `NEW` for each of those, packets associated with an `ESTABLISHED` connection would already have been accepted by that point.

Answer (score 0):

`RELATED` is useful for that kind of protocols that need to open a new connection. It is often used, in combination with `ip_conntrack_ftp` for ftp connections, take a look [here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#active) on how active ftp works.

Comment: Okay, but how is that relevant to TLS?